# How do I bind to a function inside a class and still use the event variable?

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

```
class Player():
    def __init__():
        ...
    def moveHandle(self, event):
        self.anything = ...
box.bind("<Key>", Player.moveHandle)
```

The bind function sets self as the event variable and ignores/throws up an error for event. I can't find a way to pass the event argument to the correct variable and maintain self for that function, even if I use args*. I can do one or the other, but not both.

I'm probably just lacking some basic knowledge about classes to be honest, I taught them to myself and didn't do it very thoroughly.

If I made a syntax mistake, it's because of me rewriting out the code incorrectly; in my program, the code works until the variables get passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you are trying to use an instance method as a class method.

```
consider the following:
class Player():
    def __init__():
        ...
    def moveHandle(self, event):
        self.anything = ...
box.bind("<Key>", Player.moveHandle)
```

where `box` is an instance of something, but `Player` is not.
instead this:

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def moveHandle(self, event):
        self.anything = ...
p = Player()
box.bind("<Key>", p.moveHandle)
```

creates an instance of the player class, and then binds to the instances method, not the class method.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks. What if I want the sequence to be bound to a class method, so that the code is reusable for other instances?

Comment: a class method has no reference to any instance of the class, so cannot act upon any instance without being given a reference, i'm not sure what exactly your issue is here? do you mean you wish for this event to move every player?

Comment: if you really need to pass an event to all instances or multiple instances there are ways to do that, i'm just struggling to understand why you would need that, but you can create a standalone function that you bind to, and then pass the event to the function of each instance in turn