# How do I get imported class subroutines to recognise global variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If you simply pass the imported class name to the target class, like `class TargetClass(ImportedClass):`, the imported code is unable to use global variables that have already been declared.
This means that they can't interact with their own instance.

## Code

```
from file import Class
class c(Class):
    def sub1(z):
        print(2)

    def sub3(z):
        instance.sub1() #works
        z.sub1()        #works too

instance = c()
Global = 3
instance.sub2() #can't interact with its own instance, raises an error
instance.sub3() #does not raise an error, as sub3 isn't imported
instance.sub4() #raises a NameError
```

## file.py (saved in the same file as the first code)

```
###Class in a different file###
class Class():
    def sub2(z):
        instance.sub1() #will not work
        z.sub1()        #works
    def sub4(z):
        print(Global)
```

What I want is to be able to import a class and use its subroutines as if they were already in the class.
The reason for this is that I  have a program that is very long and I want to have some of the subroutines that I don't need to develop anymore saved in a different file. Before people start suggesting different IDEs and the like, I can't use anything non-vanilla.

Comment: You should not use global variables. In this example there is no point to use global variables.
Methods should have a first parameter `self` (which you call `z` in your code). This is the current object. Use it (aka `self.sub1()`).
Also: Don't use global variables. Use class attributes instead.

Comment: Both `instance` and `Global` clearly aren't variables in the scope of `file.py`, they're undefined there. The code in `file.py` relies on something which nobody can guarantee it will be there at runtime (and in fact is not there, even at runtime, due to scoping). That's why you never write code like this.

Comment: Also, Python doesn't have subroutines, it has functions. It seems to me you're operating in the wrong paradigm here and need to start with Python again from a clean slate.

Comment: @YSelf Global variables absolutely are necessary because of modules and the fact that tkinter requires you to refer to the (global) instance of the class.

Comment: Modules do not necessitate global variables, neither does tkinter.

Comment: @deceze So you're going to just restate the problem and provide no solution? I don't see how you're helping here. Of course the imported code doesn't have those globals in their scope, that's the whole point of the question. Subroutine, function, fire hydrant, who cares?

Comment: @deceze In tkinter, to bind a key to the window, w.bind("<Key>", self.subroutine) does not work. It has to be w.bind("<Key>", instance.subroutine).

Comment: More general: Design first, implement afterwards. Your code should be split by functional boundaries, not file size.
Each interface (e.g. class) should be complete. If you need to access internals of it in other modules or if it requires global variables, it's wrong. Take a step back and redesign your program. Probably. Please.

Comment: In a nutshell, what you're doing is extremely un-pythonic and goes against most programming practices that involve scoping. Class methods are only supposed to act on `self`, you're supposed to pass values as parameters to functions and constructors to cross boundaries. Globals lead to spaghetti code and/or don't work at all, as in this case.

Comment: To your `bind`-comment: That's wrong, but probably `self` is not bound to the right object in your code. [The tkinter example](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tkinter.html#coupling-widget-variables) binds a method (`self.print_something`) to a key.

Comment: *"`w.bind("<Key>", self.subroutine)` [vs.] `w.bind("<Key>", instance.subroutine)`"* – `w.bind` doesn't care in the least whether the method is a global or a method of `self`, it works with any callable. If `self.subroutine` doesn't work, that's because `self.subroutine` doesn't exist due to issues with incorrect scoping/binding or whatever.

Comment: @deceze https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241579/how-do-i-bind-to-a-function-inside-a-class-and-still-use-the-event-variable

Comment: Yeah, that question is a different problem entirely, and the answer is merely *illustrating* the concept. It doesn't advise globals as the solution at all.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude or contrarian at all, but the fact is that, quite frankly, your code is terrible [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) and there's no easy answer to it. You *could* attempt to work around the particular hurdle you're facing right now, but that will just delay the point where you'll get tangled up in your spaghettis. The *real* solution is to learn how to write proper OOP code, which is a bit too broad to address here…

Comment: @deceze There are plenty of times when globals are fine to use in a class. Constants for example. Things like the time or random module as well. You could have them as class attributes, but they may not just apply to that class.

Comment: Sure, global values in a module are fine. You're trying to use globals to *span across* modules though, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

> If you simply pass the imported class name to the target class, like `class TargetClass(ImportedClass):`

That is not "passing the imported class", this is making `TargetClass` *inherit* from `ImportedClass`.

> the imported code is unable to use global variables that have already been declared.

There's no such thing as "global variable" in Python, in the meaning of "variables that are declared once somewhere and are then accessible everywhere in every module." Every module has its own scope. At best a variable can be *global to a module*, but never global to a program. If a name hasn't been explicitly `import`ed or defined inside a module, it doesn't exist.

> This means that they can't interact with their own instance.

The problem is that you're not trying to "interact with their own instance", you're trying to interact with names which do not exist in the module.

> ... subroutines ...

Python doesn't have subroutines, it has functions.

Some of these distinctions may seem like nitpicking, but they're important, and in your case this all adds up to some very bad spaghetti code which simply isn't easy to fix. You need to start using proper OOP practices, and stop swimming upstream against the issues you're creating for yourself. This is a broad topic, so here are simply a few pointers:

- Unless you have used `import` to import something or you have declared it in your module, it doesn't exist and you cannot use it.
- Never depend on globals in any way.
- If you `import` something, you can use it as is. Anything that can't be imported and will only be available at runtime must probably be passed as a function parameter.
- The first parameter to an instance method is named `self`. Just do it.
- Dependencies of a class are passed as parameter to `__init__`.

Stripping out the clear nonsense from your class and just leaving the somewhat sane code, you still have dependency issues:

```
class Class():
    def sub2(self):
        self.sub1()  # sub1 is not defined here, cannot be relied upon

    def sub4(self):
        print(Global)  # not defined in module, clear error
```

```
from file import Class

class c(Class):
    def sub1(self):
        print(2)

    def sub3(self):
        self.sub1()  # defined above, safe call
```

---

An example of how to do this correctly:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar  # don't use globals, pass values to the constructor

    def test(self):
        print(self.bar)  # refers to value defined in __init__, safe

    def test2(self):
        self.test()  # refers to method defined above
```

Note: everything mentioned here is clearly defined somewhere in the same file. This even includes `self`, which is explicitly passed as argument into each method. The only "external" variable is `bar` in the constructor; that's where seams to other modules/classes are created.

```
from foo import Foo  # makes Foo available in this module

class Baz(Foo):
    def toast(self):
        self.test2()  # defined in Foo, which we're inheriting from


b = Baz(42)  # passes a value across scope boundaries into Foo
b.toast()  # calls defined method, which calls defined method,
           # which calls defined method, which uses defined value
```

Comment: Self is ridiculously inefficient, so I'm alright thanks.Why type 4 characters a thousand times when I can type one? The rest is basically stuff I already know. I don't have any issues with classes, the only problem here is your inability to accept global variables being referred to in any capacity whatsoever. Sometimes the most efficient option is to refer to a global. That may be unpythonic, but if it works and it isn't slowing me down or causing a memory leak, I'll be fine.

Comment: Yes. The only issue is one of scrolling. I don't like how much code I have to scroll through, so I want to put it in a different file. The program itself works fine, I'll send it to you if you want.

Comment: No thanks. And, well… you're now discovering the limits of what "works" means when using globals.

Comment: Yeah, or I'm discovering how sad of a python community Stack Overflow has. I read about the python community being really negative and I didn't really believe it, but apparently it's true. "unpythonic" is possibly the stupidest idea I've ever heard. (This isn't aimed at you, unless you're one of the 4 downvoters)

Comment: You came here for advice and you're discounting every single thing you're told. Godspeed with your further endeavours.

Comment: The advice I've been given is rigid and condescending. "Can't do that." Why? "Because it's unpythonic". That isn't a reason. //  I give an example of code that doesn't work to illustrate the issue. "Your code is terrible". Yes but that's the point. If "that's unpythonic" was accompanied with an explanation for why that matters, then maybe I wouldn't be so frustrated. But all stack overflow seems to be is a hierarchical site, where people downvote on the slightest of whims and will only give answers to the questions they want asked.

Comment: You're simply so far off the *correct* way to do it (call that "pythonic" or whatever you want), there's no real way to help you except to tell you that you've painted yourself into a corner with your assumptions and you need to fix some fundamental practices regarding classes and globals. That may not be what *you* want to hear, but it's the only sane advice anyone can give.

Comment: First of all, if it's so many lightyears away from correct, then why does it work? Second, it's not that I don't want to hear your advice, it's just that you've given literally no justification for what you're saying. Actually explain why it's so morally reprehensible to refer to globals in classes and maybe you won't sound so ridiculous to me. Third, it was you who called it unpythonic, not me.

Comment: Functions and classes were created to solve problems with code scalability and maintainability. Specifically the kinds of problems you are running into right now. In order to solve these problems, you need to use the tools (classes and functions) effectively. The issue you’re having is that you do not use them effectively, manifesting in exactly the issues you have. I’m illustrating how classes can be used effectively and how that would solve your issues. Obviously I can only do that to some extend, especially given the sample you have provided to work with.

Comment: I cannot and won’t illustrate the entire philosophy of OOP here, since entire books have been written about it. I’m telling you that you need to start embracing OOP techniques instead of discounting them. Take the advice or don’t.

Comment: That's still not an explanation why. That's an explanation of what. Why is it specifically so disgusting to use globals in a class?

Comment: Because then if you break up that code into multiple modules, you will be referring to globals which don’t exist in your module.